# How can I enable extension from terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have looked over VsCode docs but I couldn't find any cli operation for enabling extension. There are cli options for

- --install-extension
- --uninstall-extension
- --disable-extensions
- --list-extensions
- --show-versions
- --enable-proposed-api

Are there any way of enabling extension from cli ?

Comment: Aren't they enabled by default?

Comment: I just want to enable & disable by using terminal